# anchor deploy error(devnet)

Tags: anchor, solana-program, web3.js

```
$ anchor deploy --provider.cluster devnet

Deploying workspace: https://api.devnet.solana.com
Upgrade authority: ./id.json
Deploying program "chainlink_solana_demo"...
Program path: /Users/ironmr/solana/solana-starter-kit/target/deploy/chainlink_solana_demo.so...
=========================================================================
Recover the intermediate account's ephemeral keypair file with
`solana-keygen recover` and the following 12-word seed phrase:
=========================================================================
<seed phrase here>
=========================================================================
To resume a deploy, pass the recovered keypair as the
[BUFFER_SIGNER] to `solana program deploy` or `solana write-buffer'.
Or to recover the account's lamports, pass it as the
[BUFFER_ACCOUNT_ADDRESS] argument to `solana program close`.
=========================================================================
Error: Pubsub error: ConnectionError(Io(Kind(UnexpectedEof)))
There was a problem deploying: Output { status: ExitStatus(unix_wait_status(256)), stdout: "", stderr: "" }.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

do

```
cargo clean
```

Then rebuild and  deploy